# Azure Function Service Bus Trigger Doesn't Work After the Deployment

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-deployment

I created a service bus and 2 azure functions. One azure function is a timer trigger. It triggers every minute and pushes data into the service bus. Then the other azure function triggers and starts processing that data. This setup works well on my local machine. But when I deployed these functions, only the time trigger keep pushing data. My service bus trigger function doesn't trigger.

[image: This is the Timer Trigger function]

[image: This is the Service Bus Trigger function]

After the deployement, I run service bus trigger function on my local machine again. Then I recive all enqued data.

For all 3 services, I used basic plan and recomenned settings.

Is there a specific configuration to capture enqued data from deployed azure function?

Comment: Based on your explanation, it appears that the service bus connection string is defined in the local app settings and will not be reachable when you deploy; you must configure the service bus connection string on the deployed function app configuration. Monika and RithwikBojja explained very well; check those answers for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment, and I got expected result. I have taken two triggers (Service Bus Queue Trigger and Timer Trigger) Then when i run locally i get the output as expected like below:
[image]

Then i added my connection :
In configuration section then click on apllication settings , then click on new application settings as below:

[image]

[image]
And then save it.
After that when I run my Timer Trigger it runs and when I send a message into queue it runs too.
Then when I check my logs, I am able to see my two triggers are running as below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two things to verify :

1. Double check if the connectionstring for "ConnectStringForEmailDispacher"
   is added in configuration.
   Go to Azure portal->function-> left pane ->configuration
   or depends on how you are reading in DI ( appsettings)
2. Can you check the service bus in azure portal if the message count is increasing?

Comment: ConnectStringForEmailDispacher is there in configuration.
Yes. it is enqueued every minute. I checked it in real time. When I run the service bus trigger on the local machine, it starts dequeuing.

Comment: I had set up an environment variable inside emailService.SendEmail() function. So that couldn't be read after I deployed app.

Answer (score 1):

Need to ensure that all environment variables listed in local app settings are also defined in the configuration (Azure portal > Func App > Configuration)

[image]